# AddThis buttons inside div tag not displaying inside p tag with Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, addthis

I am trying to put share buttons into a website. I found a good site called AddThis, and here is what I was able to put together:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"
  addthis:url="http://example.com"
  addthis:title="An Example Title"
  addthis:description="An Example Description">
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_badge"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_linkedin"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
  <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f0a28da71ac4a61"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

I can paste all of that into the html page, and it displays correctly. However, the link, title, and description need to be variables, not "http://example.com". The user interface is based on Javascript, and gives users articles to rate in succession. The link, title, and description variables are `story_link`, `story_title`, and `story_description`.

I tried putting all of that into a variable in Javascript:

```
var story_link_href = '<a href="' + story_link + '" target="_blank" >Read more...</a><br /><br /><!-- AddThis Button BEGIN --><div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" addthis:url="' + story_link + '" addthis:title="' + story_title + '" addthis:description="' + story_description + '"><a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a><a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_badge"></a><a class="addthis_button_linkedin"></a><a class="addthis_button_compact"></a></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f0a28da71ac4a61"></script><!-- AddThis Button END -->';
```

The problem with this is, the entire article text along with the share buttons are inside `<p>` tags. As far as I can tell, `<div>` tags don't work inside `<p>` tags.

I know almost nothing about Javascript and HTML, so everything is just a guess. I can either paste the first bunch of code straight into HTML and have a static link, or not have anything show up if I paste it into Javascript. Neither works the way it should.

Is there is a way to pass the "story_link", "story_title", and "story_description" variables into HTML, and keep passing new information as new articles come up, or is there another way to integrate that code into Javascript, with having the `<p>` still surrounding everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>`s inside `<p>` is not valid HTML, but they do work.

If you want to avaoid `<div>` inside `<p>`, replace "div" tags in addThis to "span" like below:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<span class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"
  addthis:url="http://example.com"
  addthis:title="An Example Title"
  addthis:description="An Example Description">
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_badge"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_linkedin"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
  <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f0a28da71ac4a61"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

It's not working because you can't write script tag the way you have done. You should always split the script tag or append it to the body as below:

```
var story_link = "http://google.com",
    story_title = "Title",
    story_description = "Description";

var story_link_href = '<a href="' + story_link + '" target="_blank" >Read more...</a><br /><br />'
    +'<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" addthis:url="'
    + story_link + '" addthis:title="' + story_title + '" addthis:description="' + story_description 
    + '"><a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a><a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_badge"></a><a class="addthis_button_linkedin"></a><a class="addthis_button_compact"></a></div>';


var atscript = document.createElement( 'script' );

atscript.type = 'text/javascript';
atscript.src = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f0a28da71ac4a61';
document.body.appendChild(atscript);
document.write(story_link_href)
```

Here is an update. Use this in place of the code you posted in your question. Discard above JS code I posted in this answer. I'm sure the below code will work.

```
var story_link_href = '<a href="' + story_link + '" target="_blank" >Read more...</a><br /><br />'
    +'<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" addthis:url="'
    + story_link + '" addthis:title="' + story_title + '" addthis:description="' + story_description 
    + '"><a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a><a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_badge"></a><a class="addthis_button_linkedin"></a><a class="addthis_button_compact"></a></div><scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f0a28da71ac4a61"></scr'+'ipt>';
```

Comment: That works when I paste it into HTML just the same as `<div>`, but using `<span ...></span>` instead of `<div ...></div>` in the Javascript still doesn't work.

Comment: I am still having trouble with it. I have a question, atscript.src shows a different link than the one I had. Where did that come from? Would it work to paste the `<script ...></script>` into the index.html page that calls my .js file?

Comment: Fixed. I had pasted the script which I had used in one of our websites. Put this in your JS block replacing the the one you mentioned in your question and it will work. If you still need more help, tell me where or how you are calling this JS code

Comment: I copy pasted it, but was unsuccessful. I have a file called index.mobile.erb (basically .html file) and there is a line `<script src="/javascripts/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` which is the Javascript file I am using. There is another line below that `<body onLoad="Start();" ...>` which starts all the Javascript code. There is another line a bit below that `<div id="content"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>` inside which the article and share buttons would be. It sets the HTML inside with this in file.js: `storyNode.innerHTML = tt;`, where tt is a bunch of HTML. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working even with the update. Could there be something else wrong? I don't think I know enough to answer that. Is there any information I could give on how things work that could help?

Comment: Can you share the Javascript file or use pastebin to share it's content?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6547/discussion-between-sandeep-and-eric)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to some code I had implemented which stripped "class" attributes, and it was stripping class out of the AddThis  tags. Next, the AddThis Javascript file wasn't initialized at the right place, and needed to be called with `addthis.init()` in the appropriate place. Sandeep worked with me to solve this issue, so he gets the credit.